# Is it okay to give a link to video lecture as reference source?

Tags: discussion, questions, links

Are questions like [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/516885/) allowed? It seems mentioning video link in a question post is against rules but I never get to read code of conduct until now. I explain everything in my question post and give link in the end to the lecture as these lectures are popular but still I received warning three times by the same user on linking video. Is this a bad practice?

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4918/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic that post is very helpful. Thank you:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, we expect posts to be self contained so that all details needed are provided & users do not have to go off-site to find out what you're really questioning. Hence, you should provide a link for additional *reference* to the post, but it should not be a *requirement* to understand what it is you are looking at and/or questioning.

Ben's comment says,

> Please don't post videos. Write a summary so we can tell what the argument is without watching a video.

In this case, he's right: you're requiring us to watch a video to understand what is being explained by Prof Lewin that you are questioning--you really don't describe anything in the post itself (i.e., what is $T_1$, $T_2$? What rope? What cylinder?), it's all in the video you link.

Comment: Oh right! I haven't explained about T1 & T2 at all. I agree Ben is just trying to help. I want to be efficient though. It would have been okay linking the video if I had explained T1, T2 and other missing info I hope... Thank you so much:)